Can somebody help me with emcmake error finding FindQt5.cmake
I am trying to build project on Ubuntu with this command:
emcmake cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/

and get this error
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


i checked in Qt5 folder for Qt5Config.cmake file - it's exist :/
Now i don't know what to do.
Changed -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH few times, checked using chatGTP version of Qt, Cmake and Emscripten for comparability, reinstalled Emscripten, added this to cmake file:
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/cmake/Qt5/")

That's the output when i've enabled verbose
/home/oleksiy/TestWebAssembly/CMakeLists.txt(10):  set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON )
/home/oleksiy/TestWebAssembly/CMakeLists.txt(12):  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 )
/home/oleksiy/TestWebAssembly/CMakeLists.txt(13):  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON )
/home/oleksiy/TestWebAssembly/CMakeLists.txt(20):  set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/ )
/home/oleksiy/TestWebAssembly/CMakeLists.txt(22):  find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui Quick REQUIRED )
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

i've added --debug-find flag to cmake comand, the output:
configure: cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten_debug/ --debug-find -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/share/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR=/usr/bin/node;--experimental-wasm-threads
Running with debug output on for the `find` commands.
CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package):
  find_package considered the following paths for Qt5.cmake

    /usr/share/emscripten/cmake/Modules/FindQt5.cmake
    /usr/share/emscripten/cmake/Modules/FindQt5.cmake
    /usr/share/emscripten/cmake/Modules/FindQt5.cmake
    /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindQt5.cmake

  The file was not found.

  <PackageName>_ROOT CMake variable [CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH].

    none

  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH].

    /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten-debug

  

  CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH and CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH variables
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH].

  

  Env variable Qt5_DIR [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    none

  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH env variable [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    none

  CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH and CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH env variables
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    none

  Paths specified by the find_package HINTS option.

    none

  Standard system environment variables
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    /usr/local
    /usr
    /
    /usr/games
    /usr/local/games
    /snap

  

  CMake User Package Registry [CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY].

    none

  CMake variables defined in the Platform file
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH].

    none

  CMake System Package Registry
  [CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY].

    none

  Paths specified by the find_package PATHS option.

    none

  find_package considered the following locations for the Config module:

    /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/Qt5Config.cmake
    /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/qt5-config.cmake
    /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/Qt5Config.cmake
    /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/qt5-config.cmake
    /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/Qt5Config.cmake
    /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/qt5-config.cmake

  The file was not found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package):


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/oleksiy/TestWebAssembly/build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
emcmake: error: 'cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten_debug/ --debug-find -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/share/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR=/usr/bin/node;--experimental-wasm-threads' failed (returned 1)

I can't figure out why cmake search can't follow CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TestWebAssembly VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "emcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "em++")

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

#set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Emscripten)
#set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE "/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/bin/qmake")
#set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE "/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/")
#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/cmake/Qt5/")
#set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten_debug")

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui Quick REQUIRED)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    Main.qml
)

add_executable(TestWebAssembly
    ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
)


qt5_add_resources(QT_RESOURCES qml.qrc)

target_link_libraries(TestWebAssembly PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick)

well now added full path all needed modules in cmake command:
emcmake cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/ --debug-find -DQt5_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5 -DQt5Widgets_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets -DQt5Gui_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui -DQt5Core_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Core -DQt5Svg_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Svg -DQt5Zlib_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Zlib -DQt5Network_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Network -DQt5EventDispatcherSupport_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5EventDispatcherSupport -DQt5FontDatabaseSupport_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5FontDatabaseSupport -DQt5EglSupport_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5EglSupport -DQt5Quick_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Quick -DQt5QmlModels_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5QmlModels -DQt5Qml_DIR=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Qml

if know way to automate it, let me know pls
also i've changed CMakeLists.txt like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TestWebAssembly VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "emcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "em++")

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

#set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Emscripten)
#set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE "/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/bin/qmake")
#set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE "/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/")
#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/cmake/Qt5/")
#set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten_debug")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -s FETCH")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -s MODULARIZE=1")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=\"['_main', '_embind_register_function', '_emval_as', '_emval_call', '_emval_call_method', '_emval_call_void_method', '_emval_decref', '_emval_equals', '_emval_get_global', '_emval_get_method_caller', '_emval_get_module_property', '_emval_get_property', '_emval_incref', '_emval_is_string', '_emval_new', '_emval_new_cstring', '_emval_new_object', '_emval_run_destructors', '_emval_set_property', '_emval_take_value', '_getentropy']\"")


find_package(Qt5 5.15 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui Quick)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    Main.qml
)

add_executable(TestWebAssembly
    ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
)


#qt5_add_resources(QT_RESOURCES qml.qrc)

target_link_libraries(TestWebAssembly PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Quick)

but now got this error
emmake make
make: make
CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QGifPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QICNSPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QICOPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QJpegPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QSvgIconPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QSvgPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QTgaPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QTiffPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QTuioTouchPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QWasmIntegrationPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QWbmpPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QWebpPlugin.cmake:2 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with MODULE option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:393 (include)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:218 (find_package)
  /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/oleksiy/TestWebAssembly/build-debug
[  7%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target TestWebAssembly
[  7%] Built target TestWebAssembly_autogen
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/TestWebAssembly_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/mainwindow.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QGifPlugin_Import.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QICNSPlugin_Import.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QICOPlugin_Import.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QJpegPlugin_Import.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QTgaPlugin_Import.cpp.o
[ 71%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QTiffPlugin_Import.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QWasmIntegrationPlugin_Import.cpp.o
[ 85%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QWbmpPlugin_Import.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QWebpPlugin_Import.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable TestWebAssembly.js
error: undefined symbol: _embind_register_function (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: Link with `-s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED` to get more information on undefined symbols
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0`
warning: __embind_register_function may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_as (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_as may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_call (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_call may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_call_method (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_call_method may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_call_void_method (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_call_void_method may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_decref (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_decref may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_equals (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_equals may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_get_global (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_get_global may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_get_method_caller (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_get_method_caller may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_get_module_property (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_get_module_property may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_get_property (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_get_property may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_incref (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_incref may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_is_string (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_is_string may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_new (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_new may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_new_cstring (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_new_cstring may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_new_object (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_new_object may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_run_destructors (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_run_destructors may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_set_property (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_set_property may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _emval_take_value (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __emval_take_value may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: getentropy (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: _getentropy may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
Error: Aborting compilation due to previous errors
em++: error: '/home/oleksiy/Libraries/emsdk/node/18.20.3_64bit/bin/node /home/oleksiy/Libraries/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/src/compiler.js /tmp/tmp4qyhggid.txt' failed (1)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/build.make:333: TestWebAssembly.js] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: CMakeFiles/TestWebAssembly.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2


Have you tried to set variable Qt5_DIR to the directory with file Qt5Config.cmake, as the error message suggests you? E.g. -DQt5_DIR=/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/cmake.

@Tsyvarev had just tried
emcmake cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/ -DQt5_DIR=/home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/cmake
got same error
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package):   By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but   CMake did not find one ...

CMake looks in a subdirectory of the directory you pass. Try enabling verbose mode to see the exact filenames that it tries, you should give it a directory some levels above the file

@Criminal_Affair_At_SO edited question with additional info, as you asked.

Use --debug-find

@Criminal_Affair_At_SO added output but cant understand why can't follow CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.
looks like it doesn't search where i need, even with CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. Am i right?

Can you also add the find_package line" from the CMakeLists.txt, are there any special options to find_package?

@Criminal_Affair_At_SO done.

I just reproduced this locally and I get your behavior when /home/oleksiy/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/ is not readable. I get correct behavior if the directory exists and it is readable.

@Criminal_Affair_At_SO if i now use Qt builded by me from source using Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten_debug
now i try to use emcmake cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten_debug/ --debug-find  is there any differences?

@Criminal_Affair_At_SO i configured it before build with thsi command ```emconfigure ../configure -xplatform wasm-emscripten -nomake tests -nomake examples -opensource -confirm-license -debug -skip qtwebengine -skip qt3d -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtserialport -skip qtnetworkauth -skip qtlocation -skip qtconnectivity  -skip qtremoteobjects -skip qtsensors -skip qtspeech -skip qtvirtualkeyboard -skip qtwebsockets -prefix /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten_debug


@Criminal_Affair_At_SO i've tried ```chmod a+r /home/oleksiy/InstalledLibraries/Qt_5.15.2_wasm-emscripten_debug


Try using -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/ - you will see in the debug output that CMake will actually try loading /Qt5Config.cmake. There must be something about the directory itself.

I had similar problem, that was partially solved by adding:
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE "BOTH")
